# Properly quoting SQL query with " and ' in R

Tags: r, dbi, rpostgres

I need to submit the following  query through my R code:

```
select t."date"
from db.table t
where t."date" > '2016-01-01';
```

To generate this quoted string properly, I tried:

```
sqlquery <- dbQuoteString(ANSI()
              , paste0("select t.", '"', "date", '"',"
                from db.table t
                where t.", '"',"date", '"'," > '2016-01-01';")
              )
```

Which output is:

```
<SQL> 'select t."date"
                from db.table t
                where t."date" > ''2016-01-01'';'
```

So I can use:

```
data <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sqlquery)
```

However, there are double `''` instead of a single one `'` (around 2016-01-01).
How do I overcome that?

Comment: you are doing escaping totally wrong, you should only quote the variables, individually, like `dbQuoteString(ANSI(), "2016-01-01")` and use it in place of `'2016-01-01'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several layers to this onion.

1. If you need to quote something, use `dQuote` or `sQuote`, they handle both the beginning and end for you. For instance,

   ```r
   dQuote("date")
   # [1] "\"date\""
   ```
2. The use of `dbQuoteString` is quoting your whole query as if it is a string literal. Note the `'` before `select`, indicating that it is a string literal surrounding in single quotes (a common SQL way of delineating string literals). You could also just as easily written

   ```r
   dbQuoteString(ANSI(), "Four score and seven years ago ... said by \"Lincoln\" in '1863'")
   # <SQL> 'Four score and seven years ago ... said by "Lincoln" in ''1863'''
   ```

   The reason you see `''` is because it is trying to escape the single quotes that SQL uses to surround string literals. This produces a string, not something that can be executed as a query. In fact, `dbQuoteString` is something you should be using for your original query, *instead of* literal quotes and/or my `dquote` in point 1:

   ```r
   DBI::SQL(paste("select t.", DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(DBI::ANSI(), "date"), "from db.table t where t.", DBI::dbQuoteIdentifier(DBI::ANSI(), "date"), ">", DBI::dbQuoteString(DBI::ANSI(), "2016-01-01")))
   # <SQL> select t. "date" from db.table t where t. "date" > '2016-01-01'
   ```

   (Admittedly, `DBI::SQL` is not strictly necessary here, it's really just a character string with a wrapper that makes it print more prettily on the R console.)
3. Consider not manually encoding data and such into your queries, minor mistakes break queries (or possibly worse, though unlikely in the general case). I strongly urge you to read through https://solutions.rstudio.com/db/best-practices/run-queries-safely/. There, they identify the use of `dbQuote*` functions as **"Manual escaping"**, which is the last method recommended (least-preferred while still somewhat safe). Other options include:

   - Parameterized queries, using `?` placeholders for data in the query.

     ```r
     ret <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, 'select t."date" from db.table where "date" > ?', params = list("2016-01-01"))
     ```
   - Use `glue::glue_sql`:

     ```r
     mydate <- "2016-01-01"
     sql <- glue::glue_sql(.con = con, 'select t."date" from db.table where "date" > {mydate}')
     sql
     # <SQL> select t."date" from db.table where "date" > '2016-01-01'
     ret <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql)
     ```
   - Use `DBI::sqlInterpolate`:

     ```r
     sql <- DBI::sqlInterpolate(con, 'select t."date" from db.table where "date" > ?mydate', mydate = "2016-01-01")
     sql
     # <SQL> select t."date" from db.table where "date" > '2016-01-01'
     ret <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, sql)
     ```

Comment: Great answer and reference, thank you very much @r2evans.