# R package DBI - how to add a "WHERE date > 2022-01-01" clause?

Tags: sql, r, dbi

I am using the R package DBI to extract data from a database. My query looks like this:

```
extract <- dbGetQuery(con, 
'SELECT
"one column" as onecolumn,
"other column" as othercolumn,
"timestamp"
FROM table_in_the_db')
```

The "timestamp" field is in the format `"2021-02-16 13:26:08 UTC"` in the table. I would like to add a clause that says "WHERE timestamp > 2022-01-01". I have asked ChatGPT, which suggested 3 "solutions", two of which do not impact the extract at all:

```
WHERE date(timestamp) > 2022-01-01
```

and the same with `timestamp::date`, and a solution that does not run at all, involving

```
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', timestamp) > '2022-01-01'
```

which gives the error that column '2022-01-01' can not be found.

I know that the documentation of the DBI package says it should be in the form of:

```
WHERE timestamp = ?', params = list()
```

But I could not find a way to put 'timestamp > 2022-01-01' into `list()`.

Could anyone help, please?

Comment: I think you want ... `timetamp > ?', params = list("2022-01-01")`

Comment: Thanky ou so much, @Andrew! I just didn't think of that somehow. Pls put your comment into an "Answer" so I can accept it and you get the credit.

Comment: (I would have expected that you'd need to swap the `'`s and `"`s in your query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73723824/properly-quoting-sql-query-with-and-in-r)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @JonSpring - but no, for some weird reason this is the only way it works (it cost me some gray hairs before I figured it out... :-/ )

Answer (score 0):

The (most) correct answer may depend on the database and R library database driver you are using.

However, in general, a query can be constructed like this:

```
mydate <- '2022-01-01'

extract <- dbGetQuery(con, 
'SELECT
  "one column" as onecolumn,
  "other column" as othercolumn,
  "timestamp"
FROM table_in_the_db
where timestamp::date > $1::date',
params=list(as.character(mydate)))
```

I've cast mydate as a character in the parameters list (which in this example is redundant since it's defined as a character string).  In some cases, if the class is a Date object, it may be passed to the database as an integer value from the reference date and can cause problems (depending on database and drivers).  Similarly, I've cast the query parameter $1 as a ::date to ensure the character value is resolved properly.  This approach should work in most situations for most databases.