# Properly constructing parameterized SQL queries in R

Tags: sql, r, r-dbi

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73723824/properly-quoting-sql-query-with-and-in-r) post, I thought I had this...but I continue to get an error.

I need to insert a new record into a database.  There are 11 columns in a record.

Rather than trying to use `paste0` I was trying to use `?` parameters.  So I wound up with this

```
res <- DBI::dbSendQuery(con, "INSERT INTO wuc_niin_map.wuc_niin_comments(wuc_code, mds_code, part_number_suggested, cage_code_suggested, niin_suggested, fsc_suggested, suggestion_type, per_source, user_comment, user_email, comment_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);")
                         
#bind the variables to the ? in the query string above
DBI::dbBind(res, list(commentWUC, commentMDS, commentPart, commentCage, commentNiin, commentFSC, commentType, commentSource, userComment, commentEmail, commentTime))
         
commentResult <- DBI::dbFetch(res)
         
## clear the result object for further queries.
DBI::dbClearResult(res)
         
## disconnect from db
DBI::dbDisconnect(con)
```

These are all valid variable names and the database con works as I have downloaded data.
When I run my Shiny app and exercise the functions to get to this point though, I get

[image]

Do you not comma separate the ?'s ?  Or am I missing something else here?

Comment: Generally yes, the `?`'s should be comma-separated in that context. I use parameterized queries daily, but I never bother to use it this way for inserts, preferring to use `DBI::dbWriteTable`, even with fewer columns than present in the table. Is there a particular reason you are not using this function?

Comment: I'm the guy in the office who could spell Shiny :)  I haven't written an SQL query since I took a database class as an undergrad in ~1993.  I'll look into `DBI::dbWriteTable`.  The use case here is that the use can select one or more rows from a `DT` table and the Shiny app will loop through the selections and let them enter proposed new values...those are what get pushed back to a different database for review

Comment: So would I not want `DBI::dbAppendTable` in this context?  And would the method be to create a dataframe with all those input variables, and column names that matched the database columns, and then append that?

Comment: You can use either, frankly, I believe they are similar enough under the hood. And yes, same column names. The only times it'll complain that a column is missing is if a constant is violated (e.g., `not null`) or if a value cannot be cast to the target column type (e.g., a string into an integer column).

Comment: This is a bit afield from the original question, but when I try putting all the values from the various shiny inputs into a dataframe called `commentRecord` and then calling `DBI::dbAppendTable` like this `res <- DBI::dbAppendTable(con, "wuc_niin_map.wuc_niin_comments", commentRecord)` I get an error: "Failed to initialise COPY: ERROR:  relation "wuc_niin_map.wuc_niin_comments" does not exist" But I can do `select * from wuc_niin_map.wuc_niin_comments` and that works fine....am I using `dbAppendTable` incorrectly somehow?

Comment: The way that `schema_name.table_name` is referenced is inconsistent between queries and the table-modifying commands like `dbWriteTable` and `dbAppendTable`. In a query, one can write `select * from schema_name.table_name"`, but when the `DBI` function you're calling is passed a table name as an argument, you need to use `DBI::Id`. For you, I think the call would be `DBI::dbAppendTable(con, DBI::Id(schema="wuc_niin_map", table="wuc_niin_comments"), commentRecord)`.

Comment: Thanks!  Will definitely try that and report back.  Also discovered yesterday that the DBA has the table I'd be pushing to read-only for everyone but administrators, so won't be able to test until they fix that...

Comment: I can relate, both to butting your head against the wall for doing that, _and_ for the DBA protecting data and protecting users from themselves ... it's a balance, I hope you can find some middle-ground for what you need to do.